# Floating label not working when required attribute removed

Tags: html, css

I have done a floating label to my input filed like below. And it's working fine as well. But when I remove that `required` field of input,the floating label is not working (though I don't need the `required` filed). Please suggest some ways to solve this issue.

```css
input:focus~.floating-label,
input:not(:focus):valid~.floating-label {
  top: 6px;
  bottom: 12px;
  left: 20px;
  font-size: 11px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.floating-label {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 20px;
  top: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: 0.2s ease all;
  color: #b2b2b2;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="floating_name" value="" required/>
<span class="floating-label">Enter</span>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Selector `input:focus` selects input when it get focus and Selector `input:not(:focus):valid`selects input if `valid input` not be focus.
>
> **A.** when you use `required attribute` and Do not enter any value in it:
>
> 1)Before focus and when lose focus:Nothing not be selected.(original state)
>
> 2)after focus input is invalid and it is selected with `input:focus`.
>
> **B.** when you remove `required` attribute:
>
> 1)before focus select with `input:not(:focus):valid`.
>
> 2)after focus select with `input:focus`.
>
> So, input is selected forever , And `.floating-label` will not return to the original state.

**in your question, you say:"I don't need the required filed"**

> So, remove `input:not(:focus):valid~.floating-label`.

**Full Code:**

```css
input:focus ~ .floating-label {
  top: 6px;
  bottom: 12px;
  left: 20px;
  font-size: 11px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.floating-label {
position: absolute;
pointer-events: none;
left: 20px;
top: 18px;
text-transform: uppercase;
transition: 0.2s ease all;
color: #b2b2b2;
}
```

```html
 <input type="text" id="floating_name" value="">
 <span class="floating-label">Enter</span>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot..Its working fine..But can you please explain, how a  space is important here.(between valid and bracket )

Comment: @temp , you use input:not(:focus):valid but do'nt insert to it limitation.when you use input:not(:focus) :valid remove this problem.

Answer (score 5):

Please try this another method which can be done **without 'required'  attribute**

use ':placeholder-shown'

The :placeholder-shown CSS pseudo-class represents any input or textarea element that is currently displaying placeholder text.

so there are 2 cases for label to be floated

- when placeholder not visible (that is when there is data in field)
- when the field is focused

and 1 case for label not to be floated

- when placeholder is visible ( that is when no data in field)

fiddle : [floating label demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Prajeesh_PR/ke17nsrh/)

```css
.form-group {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}
input:placeholder-shown + .form-control-placeholder{
  margin-top:0%;
}

input + .form-control-placeholder ,
.form-control:focus + .form-control-placeholder{
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 200ms;
  margin-left:-25%;
  margin-top:-3%;
}
```

```html
<br><br>
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder=" " >
  <label class="form-control-placeholder" for="name">Name</label>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. The other answers don't work, because when the input is blurred, the label no longer floats.

Answer (score 2):

The `:valid` selector only works for form elements with limitations. When you remove `required` part of your CSS no longer applies. I removed `input:not(:focus):valid ~ .floating-label` and it works again.

```css
input:focus~.floating-label {
  top: 6px;
  bottom: 12px;
  left: 20px;
  font-size: 11px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.floating-label {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 20px;
  top: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: 0.2s ease all;
  color: #b2b2b2;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="floating_name" value="" />
<span class="floating-label">Enter</span>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. This also working fine.But still I need that valid to avoid other overlapping issues.

Answer (score 1):

try this. Using input:not(:placeholder-shown) should definitly work:

```css
input:focus ~ .floating-label,
input:not(:placeholder-shown) ~ .floating-label{
  top: 8px;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 20px;
  font-size: 11px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.inputText {
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 35px;
}

.floating-label {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 20px;
  top: 18px;
  transition: 0.2s ease all;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input placeholder="" type="text" class="inputText" />
  <span class="floating-label">Your email address</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 function checkForInput(element) {
        // element is passed to the function ^

        const $label = $(element).siblings('label');

        if ($(element).val().length > 0) {
            $label.addClass('input-has-value');
        }

         else {
            $label.removeClass('input-has-value');
        }
    }

    // The lines below are executed on page load
    $('input').each(function () {
        checkForInput(this);
    });

    // The lines below (inside) are executed on change & keyup
    $('input').on('change keyup', function () {
        checkForInput(this);
    });

     $('input').focus(function () {
         const $label = $(this).siblings('label');
         $label.addClass('input-has-value');
    });
```

Comment: .form-group,
.form-wrap {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

.form-control-placeholder {
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    padding: 7px 0 0 13px;
    transition: all 200ms;
    opacity: 1;
}

.form-control:focus + .input-has-value,
.form-control:valid + .input-has-value {
     font-size: 15px;
     transform: translate3d(0, -130%, 0);
     opacity: 1;
     color: #101712;
}
.form-control:focus {
    border-color: #95996f;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgb(149, 153, 111);
}

Comment: Please put your answer always in context instead of just pasting code. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more details.